# Heading Text Being Cut Off On Mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple website and the text in one of my heading elements is being hidden/cutoff when viewed on certain mobile devices. This happens when viewed both in Chrome developer tools simulating a mobile device (Galaxy S5) and when viewed in an actual mobile device (Galaxy S5) in chrome. I could not replicate the problem when viewing with the standard browser of an iPhone 6.  I've adjusted the CSS to no avail.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Concierge</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles/home.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="flex-nav">
      <a class="toggleNav">☰ Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Multifaceted Approach</a></li>
        <li><a>Guest Version</a></li>
        <li><a>Administrator Version</a></li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://twitter.com/MultifacetedApp"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://facebook.com/MultifacetedApproach"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="introduction">
      <h1>Concierge</h1>
      <h3>Give Your Guests The Ultimate Experience</h3>
      <img src="images/introduction.png">
    </section>
    <section class="ourMission">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <p>People are demanding more and more when it comes to technology. Guests in the hospitality industry are no different.
        We designed Concierge to give hotels, bed & breakfasts, and resorts a way to interact with their guests in a way
        that suits their needs of the new digital age.Concierge consists of a 'Guest' and 'Administrator' version. Each application
        is different, but works with the other to enhance your guests' stay and increase your organization's efficiency.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="communication">
      <h2>Communication</h2>
      <h3>Real-time two-way communication is the heart of what makes Concierge a true asset to your organization</h3>
      <img src="images/communication.png" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="guestFeatures">
      <h2>Guest Features</h2>
      <div class="sideBySideImage">
        <h3>Concierge includes all of the standard features of a traditional alarm-clock radio</h3>
        <img src="images/guestFeaturesAlarm.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/guestFeaturesMain.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="sideBySideImage">
        <h3>Allow your guests to search for local attractions and stay on top of the most recent news headlines</h3>
        <img src="images/guestFeaturesYelp.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/guestFeaturesNews.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="administratorFeatures">
      <h2>Administrator Features</h2>
      <img src="images/administratorFeatures.png" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="signup">
      <h2>Request Free Demo Access</h2>
      <form method="POST" action="/demo/organization" class="signup">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input name="organization" type="text" placeholder="Your Organization">
        <input type="submit" value="Learn more">
      </form>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Multifaceted Approach, LLC</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // document.ready shorthand
    $(function () {
      $('.toggleNav').on('click', function () {
        $('.flex-nav ul').toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* General CSS Styling */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #202020, #000000, #202020);
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
  padding: 20px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  color: black;
}

.toggleNav {
  display: none;
}

.introduction img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

section,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #5092d3;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: black;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: black;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}


/* Specific Section/Portion Styling */

.sideBySideImage {
  width: 100%;
}

.sideBySideImage img {
  width: 49%;
}

.communication img,
.administratorFeatures img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.introduction,
.guestFeatures {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #202020, #000000, #202020);
}

.ourMission {
  background: #00345a;
}

.ourMission h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ourMission p {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  color: #5092d3;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.communication,
.administratorFeatures {
  background: black;
}

footer {
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* Flex Container */

.flex-nav ul {
  border: 1px solid white;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}


/* Flex Item */

.flex-nav li {
  flex: 3;
}

.flex-nav .social {
  flex: 1;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: #1da1f2;
}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  .flex-nav ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-nav li {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
  .flex-nav .social {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
  }
}


@media all and (max-width:500px),
(max-device-width:500px) {
  a {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  input,
  input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .flex-nav li {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  /* Turn on flexbox */
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* Reorder items */
  .wrapper>* {
    order: 999;
  }
  /* Nav */
  .flex-nav {
    order: 1;
  }
  .toggleNav {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .flex-nav ul.open {
    display: flex
  }
}
```

[Mobile Screenshot Of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m9x2.png)

Comment: When running your code in Chrome Developer Tools in responsive mode, I don't get the text cut off -- it shrinks down with plenty of padding. The code above definitely does not replicate this problem -- it has a few missing end tags, so perhaps you have some additional code that is causing the problem. Do you use any frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation? Could you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Cheers :)

Comment: your CSS ended prematurely. and do you know you should be using a meta viewport tag so your page scales down on mobile devices?

Comment: I have added the missing tags, no I am not using any frameworks, and the problem seems not to affect responsive mode, but it does affect Galaxy S5. @Obsidian Age

Comment: I created this jsfiddle of your HTML and CSS and have no padding or margin issues on safari or chrome on my iPhone. https://jsfiddle.net/byqkhvLp/. I'll add this to your question to help people test in the event I've missed the issue your referencing.

Comment: I guess I didn't know that @MichaelCoker, what would it look like here?

Comment: it's fairly standard, causes the content to scale `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Wow, that must be something I just never learned. I have always used Bootstrap before this, and for some reason I thought that meta tag was specific to Bootstrap only --> DUMB Thanks! @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embarrassing to admit, but the problem was the omission of a meta viewport tag. Once this was added to the page, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bootstrap to add a `<div class="container-fluid">` and nest the header that's causing you problems within it.

Play around with bootstrap, it'll help make your page responsive to all screen sizes and specifications. By the way, i tested your HTML on a mobile device and didn't see any problems with the headings.